# Notifying app after an entry or update in remote database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, service, broadcastreceiver

I m new to `Android` and have developed an app that inserts and update data into remote
  MySql database and i m able to display it in list view also using `JSON` object.
  Now i want notify app when ever i insert or update data in database using background 
  services even though less efficient than `GCM`.

```
   public class Myservice extends Service
  {
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
   {
    //TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
   {
   //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
   return null;
   }
 }
```

I referred some links and vogella tutorials but it is for alarm manager.I need for database Can somebody provide some code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a background task and polling your server for update is a very bad idea, as it has pleanty of drawbacks. I would advice you to use GCM. As its very easy to implement.([GCM with php](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and [GCM with java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/ce24ca647c8086cf677b93d0c97c682b9137650b/sdk/extras/google/gcm?autodive=0))

However, Since you want a service based approach:

Try using the [alarm managers](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html), as they can save you on power.

1. Set up an AlarmManager to fire in say 10 minutes. In response to the
2. alarm, start a service that polls the data. After polling it should
3. set itself up with a new Alarm to fire again in another 10 minutes.
4. The service shuts itself down.

*Note:

   I will still urge you to use gcm as they are very efficient at doing that one thing(polling for updates).*

Comment: Thanks for idea can u provide code examples that how to retrieve from server side to app using java..

Comment: @user3620233 I have update my answer with the link... :)